# Mongoose not inserting into MongoDB properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I run this code in my node script, for some reason when I check the db using db.test.find(), nothing shows up. Any clues?

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
  UserSchema = new Schema({
  'title': { type: String, index: true },
  });
  var User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
  var user = new User();
  user.title = "TEST TITLE";
  user.save();
```

Thanks guys

Comment: That's a shell command that I run in the mongodb shell

Comment: Where is your code checking for the success of the save() operation?

Comment: So I found out the name of my collection was called "users" and obviously when I do db.test.find(), the query won't show anything. So instead, when I used the command db.users.find(), my TEST_TITLE showed up.

So just a tip for you guys - the command "show collections" in the mongodb shell displays all the collections available in the current database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the database 'test' in the console. Why test? because you're telling it to in this line:

`var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');`

Console:

`> use test`

Also with mongoose; it pluralizes the collection, so its saving it into "users".

`> db.users.find()`